# Multiple return types and attribute types

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, return-type

I have the following class

```
public class Expression<T> {
    private T expression;

    public Expression (T expression) {
        this.setExpression(expression);
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

and multiple types that look like this

```
public class Load {
    private Variable memory;
    private Variable address;
    private long size;

    // constructor, getters and setters
}
```

and another one that takes both Expressions and Variables:

```
public class Def {
    private Variable lhs;
    private Expression<?> rhs;

    public Def(Variable lhs, Expression<?> rhs) {
        this.setLhs(lhs);
        this.setRhs(rhs);
    }
}
```

Now I would like to create definitions of different Expression types, such as Load, Store etc.
However, I will only know at runtime what type of Expression it will be and all those subtypes only store the variables and do not have any other methods than getters and setters.

I have a function that checks what the current Expression type is and this function has multiple return types Expression. I was not able to figure out how to define such a function.
Here is one attempt, however, I can only extend one class:

```
protected Expression<? extends Load> createExpression(PcodeOp pcodeOp) {
    
    Varnode[] inputs = pcodeOp.getInputs();
    String mnemonic = pcodeOp.getMnemonic();
    
    if(mnemonic == "LOAD") {
        Expression<Load> loadExp = new Expression<Load>();
        return loadExp;
    } 
    else if(mnemonic == "STORE") {
        Expression<Store> storeExp = new Expression<Store>();
        return storeExp;
    }
    else if(mnemonic == "PIECE") {
        Expression<Concat> concatExp = new Expression<Concat>();
        return concatExp;
    }
    else if(mnemonic == "SUBPIECE") {
        Expression<Extract> extractExp = new Expression<Extract>();
        return extractExp;
    }
    else if(isBinOp(mnemonic)) {
        Expression<BinOp> binOpExp = new Expression<BinOp>();
        return binOpExp;
    }
    else if(isUnOp(mnemonic)) {
        Expression<UnOp> unOpExp = new Expression<UnOp>();
        return unOpExp;
    }
    else if(isCast(mnemonic)) {
        Expression<Cast> castExp = new Expression<Cast>();
        return castExp;
    }
}
```

This function in still incomplete as I still have to add all Variables to each type.

I am relatively new to Java and haven't found any other good implementation yet. If someone knows a better way to implement that, I'd be happy to hear that.

Comment: `mnemonic == "SUBPIECE"` -> [How do I compare Strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Thanks, but this does not help me with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in a "nice" and safe way. Because you have no type associated with the `PcodeOp`. But what you can do is to simply add a generic parameter to your method:

```
protected <T> Expression<T> createExpression(PcodeOp pcodeOp) {
```

So when you call the method you can provide a type:

```
Expression<Store> exp = this.createExpression(pcodeOp);
// or 
Expression<Store> exp = this.<Store>createExpression(pcodeOp);
```

But that is all you can get with your current setup.

Comment: It seems, that I need to find another way to implement it. Unfortunately, I only know the type at runtime. I would directly put the result of the function in the Def constructor like  `new Def(createVariable(pcodeOp.getOutput(), nodeContxt), createExpression(pcodeOp)))`

Comment: @Melvin well when you only know the type at runtime then there is sadly no "safe" way where the compiler can help you. Unless of course you have a generic type parameter on all your methods, but that would still get cumbersome

Answer (score 0):

> „*If someone knows a better way to implement that, I'd be happy to hear that*“

Are *`Enum<E…>`* types something you would consider?…

```
enum Mnemonic {
    
    LOAD, STORE, CONCAT( "PIECE" ), EXTRACT( "SUBPIECE" ) /* … */;
    
    …
}
```

If so, then an *experimental* implementation of a generic *`Expression< … >`* class might look something like…

```
class Expression< M extends Enum< M > > { 
    
    private M mnemonic;

    public Expression( M mnemonic ){ this.mnemonic = mnemonic; }
    
    …        
    
    /* other members elided */

}
```

And an *experimental* *`createExpression( … )`* could be simplified to…

```
…
protected Expression< Mnemonic > createExpression( OpCode opCode ) { 

    switch( opCode.getMnemonic( ) ) { 
        
        case LOAD :
            return new Expression< Mnemonic >( LOAD );
            
        case STORE :
            return new Expression< Mnemonic >( STORE );
            
        case CONCAT :
            return new Expression< Mnemonic >( CONCAT );
            
        case EXTRACT :
            return new Expression< Mnemonic >( EXTRACT );
            
        /* … */
        
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

You can [*observe an experimental run of this*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_309954)…

```
…
Experiment experiment = new Experiment( );   
…
OpCode opCode = new OpCode( LOAD );
    
assertMnemonicEquals( opCode, LOAD );
…
assertMnemonicEquals( experiment.createExpression( opCode ), LOAD );
    
assertMnemonicEquals( experiment.createExpression( new OpCode( STORE ) ), STORE );
    
assertMnemonicEquals( experiment.createExpression( new OpCode( CONCAT ) ), CONCAT );
    
assertMnemonicEquals( experiment.createExpression( new OpCode( EXTRACT ) ), EXTRACT );
…
```

…results in…

```
EXPERIMENT SUCCESSFUL
```

This solution has the additional advantage of potentially being leverage to persuade your boss to [*upgrade to JDK 14*](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/14/). The [*Switch Expression feature*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/361) (*now a standard feature in JDK 14<sup>+</sup>*) would improve the efficiency and the simplicity of this proposed solution even more. And [*the planned Pattern Matching feature*](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Ebriangoetz/amber/pattern-match.html#deconstruction-patterns) would improve it even more still.